# How can I close a current form and then open the main one in C#?

Tags: c#

I'm able to get my first form, titled "*FieldReprogrammingSoftware*" to close and another form called "Setup" to open using the following code.

```
            Setup fh = new Setup();
            fh.Show();
            this.Hide();
```

However I can't seem to do the same type of thing to get back to *FieldReprogrammingSoftware* because that name isn't even an option in the *Setup* code. If I try to just type *FieldReprogrammingSoftware* I get an error saying:

> The name 'FieldReprogrammingSoftware'
>   does not exist in the current context

Any Ideas?

Please keep in mind that I'm a noob to C#.

NVM, I just found out that for this product it is ok to have the *FieldReprogrammingSoftware* form stay open while the *Setup* form is up so I'm now just using

```
        Setup fh = new Setup();
        fh.Show();
```

on the *FieldReprogrammingSoftware* form and

```
this.close()
```

on the setup form. God this was alot easier to do in VB

And the namespace for both forms is FieldUpdate, which is what my Solution is called.

Comment: FieldProgrammingSoftware does not exist in the current namespace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**In the Setup form you can use this:**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Application.OpenForms[0].Show();
    this.Hide(); // or this.Close();
}
```

this will show the first form again. "0" is the index of the application's main form.

Comment: This will only work if his MainForm was indeed the first item in the collection.  That may be a fair assumption under normal circumstances, but you can't always guarantee that.

Comment: Im assuming by the title of his question that "main" is the initial form.

Comment: he might think its his initial form, but it doesn't solve the problem when its not the first form in the list.

Comment: I agree, but nothing prevents anyone from checking this programmatically instead of hardcoding the index.

Comment: It is the first form and this works. Good to know in case I need to use it another time, thanks.

Comment: @Bryan, not taking away from this answer and i know it works, just keep in mind that when you need to do this with something other than your main form your index will not be 0, and you will have to find the form you are looking for to activate it.

Comment: I'm aware, that is pretty much standard with any index reference. Or at least any I've seen. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You either have to pass in the instance of the main form to `Setup` or create a static variable to hold the main form in.

You can also subscribe to `Setup` Form Closed event and then show the form again.

Like so

```
        Setup setupForm = new Setup();
        setupForm.Show();
        setupForm.FormClosed += (o,e) => this.Show();
        this.Hide();
```

**Edit for .NET 2.0**

```
        Setup setupForm = new Setup();
        setupForm.Show();
        setupForm.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(setupForm_Closed);
        this.Hide();


 void setupForm_Closed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Show();
        }
```

Comment: Ooh, I like this method.  I opted for the singleton approach to store globally accessible forms but this is nice too if you want the main form to handle it's own re-opening.  Nice approach.

Comment: @Ben, thanks. I had suggested static as well, there are many ways to skin a cat :)

Comment: +1 Be aware though that this will only work if the main form is supposed to be loaded every time that form is closed.  If the other scenario of needing to open the calling form, then he'd need to take a different approach.

Comment: This code gives me all sorts of errors about needing multiple 0 and ; and invalid ) and > expressions

Comment: @Bryan, are you using .NET 3.5 ? if not see my edited answer.

Comment: @Bryan, by the way thats the letter "o" its not zero (0)

Answer (score 4):

In the situation you've described, you want the original instance back.  You've used `this.hide` to hide the form.

Obviously you don't want to new up another instance as that wastes resources; what you need to do is store the initial instance somewhere you can get at it from the child form.

There are a few methods of doing this, but I would probable take one of two approaches:

**Singleton:**

Store your main form in the singleton so that when you need to get it back you can refer to the stored instance rather than newing up another instance wastefully.

```
public static class GlobalForms
{
    private MainForm _main;
    public MainForm Main
    {
        get
        {
            if (_main == null) _main = new MainForm();
            return _mainForm;
        }
    }

}
```

Now when you want the MainForm, instead of newing it up you would reference the singleton.

```
Form mainInstance = GlobalForms.Main
mainInstance.Show();
//Do any other stuff for your main form.
this.Hide(); //Or this.Close();
```

This is lazy loaded so it won't create an instance of the main form until you need it the first time.  After that it'll be held until you need it again unless you dispose of it in which case the cycle will begin again.

**Opening the second form as a child of the first:**

```
Form otherForm = new OtherForm();
otherForm.Show(this); //This sets up the main form as the owner of this one for this call
this.Hide();
```

Alternatively if you want OtherForm opened as a modal dialog (i.e. you are unable to interact with other windows while this one is open), then do `otherForm.ShowDialog(this);`

And from OtherForm:

```
this.Owner.Show();
this.Close();
```

Alternatively, [Stan R](https://stackoverflow.com/users/119929/stan-r) has discussed [a neat idea using an event handler to catch the close event of the child form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051881/how-can-i-close-a-current-form-and-then-open-the-main-one-in-c/2051939#2051939).  Although, this can potentially get complex if you have multiple forms opening your child form, so if this form is a common dialog for many forms, this approach should be used with caution.

You could also access the Application.OpenForms collection to get at forms that are currently open within your application.  You will need to know the index of the form you are wishing to activate.

Each approach has its drawbacks.  Naturally, the route you take will complement the rest of your architecture and design practices so that your code is consistent to maintain.

Comment: @Ben, when you call this from the child form you wouldn't be able to use **using**,am I correct?

Comment: @Stan Good catch, thanks.  You're right I've corrected my code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to use the Setup form temporarily, another approach would be to open the form as a dialog.

```
using(Setup fh = new Setup())
{
     this.Hide();
     fh.ShowDialog();
     this.Show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Follow your heart, let the error message be your guide.**

Check your FieldProgrammingSoftware form's **Namespace**, located at the top of your code file, just underneath of your using statements.  Sometimes, espeically when copying code over, or adding new forms from other projects, it's easy to intermingle namespaces.

For instance, if you create a new project called **WindowsApplication1**, all new forms you add to your project will automatically inherit that namespace and will have **WindowsApplication1** as their namespace.  If you add a form from another project to your existing project, it will keep the namespace from the other project.

If you are not intentionally adding a new namespace to your code, which it doesn't sound like you are doing, just ensure both match (or both at least have namespaces).  Otherwise, either add the new namespace or click at the end of the object that you do not get intellisense on and press **Ctrl .** to see if VS can find your objects namespace for you.

Comment: It's an awesome answer. Now I want to know what the question is.